# Не сочетается предлог

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

*Курсы для специалистов, работающих **с** профессиональной ориентацией молодежи.*

Не сочетается предлог "с" с оставшимся предложением? Кажется, что есть какая-то стилистическая ошибка. Следует ли заменить предлог?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше написать так: *Курсы для специалистов **по профессиональной ориентации молодежи**.*

Из словаря:

**СПЕЦИАЛИСТ**, -а; м. 1. Человек, профессионально владеющий какой-л. специальностью (2 зн.); представитель какой-л. специальности. Подготовка специалистов. Привлечь к участию в работе специалистов. Заключение, мнение специалистов. Узкий с. Крупный с. в области радиотехники. **С. по сельскому хозяйству.** С. широкого профиля.